# Using YQL to get JSON data from cross-domain server, how to create a table with retrieved data

Tags: javascript, json, yql

I did a cross-domain JSON request with YQL and it returns me the JSON code in a table `<div>` in the html file.

Now my problem is that I don't know to get this data and put it in a table.

This is the code (in JS file):

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){
var container = $('#target');
$('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
doAjax($(this).attr('href'));
return false;
});
function doAjax(url){

// if it is an external URI

if(url.match('^http')){

// call YQL
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
"q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
encodeURIComponent(url)+
"%22&format=xml'&callback=?",

// this function gets the data from the successful 
// JSON-P call

function(data){

// if there is data, filter it and render it out

if(data.results[0]){
var data = filterData(data.results[0]);
container.html(data);

// otherwise tell the world that something went wrong

} else {
var errormsg = "<p>Error: can't load the page.</p>";
container.html(errormsg);
}
}
);

// if it is not an external URI, use Ajax load()

} else {
$('#target').load(url);
}
}

// filter out some nasties

function filterData(data){
data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g,'');
data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g,'');
data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g,'');
data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g,'');
data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g,'');
data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/,'');
return data;
}
});
```

and here is the html code:

```
<body>
<div id="doc" class="yui-t7">
<div id="hd" role="banner">
<h1>
Ajax with jQuery - using YQL
</h1>
</div>
<div id="bd" role="main">
<h2>
Demo
</h2>
<ul>
<li>
<a class="ajaxtrigger" href="ajaxcontent.html">
Load Ajax Content
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="ajaxtrigger" href="linkpage"> 
Get cspro.json
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="target">
<!--    <script>window.alert(container)</script> -->
</div>
<h2>
Formatted List
</h2>
</div>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<!--  <script> document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML =     container.html(data);
</script> -->
<h2>
TEST
</h2>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script src="code.js"></script>
<script src="using-yql3.js"></script>
</body>
```

I've try with:

```
//      $.getJSON(data, function(json){
// figure out the format of the answer here...      
//        
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=prova.buy.currency+"  "+prova.sell.currency+" "+prova.offer[0].amount+" "+prova.offer[0].rate+"  "+prova.offer[0].seller.name;
```

but it didn't work.

***(UPDATE) after your indications, I've tested this:***

```
// TEST

  $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=json'&callback=?",  // QUESTO è URL cui segue la "," e poi function(data)

    // this function gets the data from the successful 
    // JSON-P call
    function(data){
    document.getElementById('placeholder').value = JSON.stringify(data,null,'  '); //MIO
      // if there is data, filter it and render it out
      if(data.results[0]){
        var data = filterData(data.results[0]);
        container.html(data);
        alert(data);    //MIO TEST
      // otherwise tell the world that something went wrong
      } else {
        var errormsg = "<p>Error: can't load the page.</p>";
        container.html(errormsg);
      }
    }
  );
```

but it works up to alert(data) simply "jumping" the part of the code related to document.getElementById.

I've also changed the "xml" request into "json" request...

***SECOND UPDATE***

I've solved the problem with the "div id=placeholder" in the html table. Seems it has some problems with this div, considering that changing the "div id" with a "texture id=placeholder" it works.

So, now I have the whole json string in my text area.
I've tried the getJson command to recover a parte of the data and get it in a table, but again I've having some problems.

I can't understand with the code you suggested to me, I have a json code, why I can't extract it and show the part i need?

***FINAL PARTIAL UPDATE***

The problem was that the "data" filter wasn't eliminating "" tag from data, so that the parse.Json(data) was unable to read the format!

Right know I retrieve the information I need.

Here's the final .js code:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){
var container = $('#target');
$('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
doAjax($(this).attr('href'));
return false;
});
function doAjax(url){
// if it is an external URI
if(url.match('^http')){
// call YQL

// TEST

$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=json'&callback=?",
    // this function gets the data from the successful 
    // JSON-P call
    function(data){
      // if there is data, filter it and render it out
        if(data.results[0]){
            **var data = filterData(data.results[0]);**

            container.html(data);
            alert(data);    // TEST VERIFY (after FILTER before data extraction)
            document.getElementById("prova1").value = data; // TEST full data return in a textarea

            var obj = $.parseJSON(data); // JSON elements retrieve
            alert(obj.sell.currency); // TEST for element retrieve
// TEST END

      // otherwise tell the world that something went wrong
      } else {
        var errormsg = "<p>Error: can't load the page.</p>";
        container.html(errormsg);
      }
    }
  );
// if it is not an external URI, use Ajax load()
} else {
  $('#target').load(url);
 }
}

 // filter out some nasties
 function filterData(data){
 **data = data.replace(/<body>/,'');** // INTERTED THIS ONE TO REMOVE body tag
 data = data.replace(/<?\/body[^>]*>/g,'');
 data = data.replace(/[\r|\n]+/g,'');
 data = data.replace(/<--[\S\s]*?-->/g,'');
 data = data.replace(/<noscript[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/noscript>/g,'');
 data = data.replace(/<script[^>]*>[\S\s]*?<\/script>/g,'');
 data = data.replace(/<script.*\/>/,'');
 return data;
 }
});
```

Comment: From the code it appears you are requesting XML rather than json, i.e., format=xml.  See: [Using JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) with Yahoo! Web Services](https://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/json.html#xml)

Comment: @Alberto rather than changing your title to have "solved", answer the question below so that others can benefit.

Comment: I'va inserted the problem solition inside my first post and i've added "solved" in title to comunicate there's the solution inside... What was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are requesting data in XML format. Suggest changing your query string to format=json.  That will return a javascript object that you can work with more easily.

Since you are already using jQuery I highly recommend the [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) plug-in.

Here's a code snippet that illustrates the data formats returned from Yahoo. And the [Yahoo Console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) is also very helpful when testing.

```html
<html>
 <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <button onclick="json()">GET JSON</button><button onclick="xml()">GET XML</button>
    
    <textarea id="stdout" style="width:100%;height:40em;"></textarea>
    
   <script type="text/javascript">
     
   function json() {  
     var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=show%20tables&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?';
     $.getJSON( url, function(data) {
          document.getElementById('stdout').value = JSON.stringify(data,null,'  ');
     });
   }
     
   function xml() {  
     var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=show%20tables&format=xml&diagnostics=true&callback=?';
     $.getJSON( url, function(data) {
           document.getElementById('stdout').value = JSON.stringify(data,null,'  ');
     });
   }
     
   </script>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this library: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/jQuery-cross-domain-requests